# Downloaded game to wrong account, can i swap the license from my friends account to mine?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I accidentally downloaded modern warfare 4 remastered to my friends account as for some reason my ps4 logged him in, it won't allow me to access the game as the license is in his name, please can someone help me get it to my account!!!

Comment: You understand your friends account will lose access to the game right?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone can help you in this instance, it's sony support.

For this, you would have to show that you made the purchase, that you were logged into the wrong account, and even then, it's rare that they'll do anything.  It's possible that he could call, explain what happened, and have them refund it (Which is exceptionally rare, they list in their terms of service that purchases are non-refundable, so they'll likely say no).

Basically, you should have whoever actually made the purchase (I.E. Whoever's credit card was used) call sony support to get it refunded and then re-purchase it on the correct account.  If you're polite and explain what happened, it's possible they'll issue a refund, but it's honestly hit or miss.  I've been able to get a refund in store credit before, but only because I purchased the wrong version of a game (meant to buy the deluxe edition instead of standard, for example) and it sounds like store credit won't really help you here, as it would then be on your friends account.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if it's on the same system, you still should be able to play the game, on your account on the same system, as long as your friend's account is existing on your system you should have no trouble.